# WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start error with Selenium Edge Chromium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am getting the below error while trying to run selenium using java in Edge Chromium browser

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'
System info:  os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_271'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver

Code which I am trying

```
    String edgeDriverPath = propertiesOperations.getPropertyValues("edge_driver_path");
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", path + edgeDriverPath);
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
    driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me when I had the driver in a shared folder (not in C drive). I moved the driver to C drive and it solved the problem.
It took too much time to run/execute the driver if it is located in a shared drive, so it caused time out error.